# limiting elements in the list view

Tags: android, listview

I m working on a chatting app.i had populated my `Listview` with the *mesText*, *mesTime* and *userid*.But when i populate the `Listview`,the new item get added at the last of the `Listview`.So,i want to limit the number of element shown once in the `Listview`.

The following is the code where I populate the `Listview`.

```
    private void displayChatMessage(){
        final ListView listofmessage= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message); //list view where i populate the data
        adapter=new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.list_item,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                TextView messagetext,messaggeuser,messagetime;
                messagetext=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                messaggeuser=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                messagetime=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                messagetext.setText(model.getMessagetext());
                messaggeuser.setText(model.getMessageuser());
                messagetime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-mm-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessagetime())); 

            }
        };
        listofmessage.setAdapter(adapter); //firebase adapter where i update the data
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend to do it on server side. You can have limit on server side and then fetch the remaining data. You can have page number indicator in your REST API which helps you in optimizing further

Comment: what is the need to put limit? you can use listview.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount()-1); for set the item at last position when you get new data or send message. and one more thing you can use that when you fetch data from db or other you can get with limit and use refresh view and on refresh can get previous data.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the getView method in the adapter, you can restrict the elements by putting check on getItem(position).